# C# Thread Sync Monitor + ResetEvent

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have written a DirectSoundWrapper but I just can access the interfaces through MTA Threads.
So I created a Thread that is working in background and executes actions in a queue. 
I've done something like this:

```
private void MTAQueue()
{
    lock (queueLockObj)
    {
        do
        {
            if (marshalThreadItems.Count > 0)
            {
                MarshalThreadItem item;
                item = marshalThreadItems.Dequeue();
                item.Action();
            }
            else
            {
                Monitor.Wait(queueLockObj);
            }
        } while (!disposing);
    }
}
```

And I Execute an Action like this:

```
private void ExecuteMTAAction(Action action)
{
    if (IsMTAThread)
        action();
    else
    {
        lock (queueLockObj)
        {
            MarshalThreadItem item = new MarshalThreadItem();
            item.Action = action;
            marshalThreadItems.Enqueue(item);

            Monitor.Pulse(queueLockObj);
        }
    }
}
```

But now I wanted to wait for the finishing the action is called. So I wanted to use a ManuelResetEvent:

```
private void ExecuteMTAAction(Action action)
{
    if (IsMTAThread)
        action();
    else
    {
        lock (queueLockObj)
        {
            MarshalThreadItem item = new MarshalThreadItem();
            item.Action = action;
            item.waitHandle = new ManualResetEvent(false); //setup
            marshalThreadItems.Enqueue(item);

            Monitor.Pulse(queueLockObj); //here the pulse does not pulse my backgrond thread anymore
            item.waitHandle.WaitOne(); //waiting
        }
    }
}
```

And my background thread i just edit like this:

```
item.Action();
item.waitHandle.Set();
```

The problem is that the background thread does not get pulsed anymore and just keeps waiting (Monitor.Wait(queueLockObj)) and my mainthread that calls the action waits on the manuelresetevent...?

Why?

Answer (score 0):

Problem in your code is that before `Monitor.Wait(queueLockObj)` will exit and thread can process item another thread (`ExecuteMTAAction` method) must call `Monitor.Exit(queueLockObj)`, but call to `item.waitHandle.WaitOne()` is preventing this call - and you have dead lock. So - you must call `Monitor.Exit(queueLockObj)` before `item.waitHandle.WaitOne()`.
This code will work fine:

```
private void ExecuteMTAAction(Action action)
{
    if (IsMTAThread)
        action();
    else
    {
        lock (queueLockObj)
        {
            MarshalThreadItem item = new MarshalThreadItem();
            item.Action = action;
            item.waitHandle = new ManualResetEvent(false); //setup
            marshalThreadItems.Enqueue(item);

            Monitor.Pulse(queueLockObj);
        }
            item.waitHandle.WaitOne(); //waiting           
    }
}
```